# Asymmetric encryption with master Key

Tags: wallets, dapps, ipfs, encryption

Is there any way i can derive private and public keypairs from a Master Key? The Master Key should be able to decrypt every encryption made with the generated Keypairs.

to explain a bit further i want to save encrypted data on IPFS, which can only be accessed by the creator with its own private key and an admin which should have access to all encrypted data within the system.

I have read about deterministic wallets but i'm not sure if these are capable of what i want and how they work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Encrypt data using public key](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/61181/encrypt-data-using-public-key)
The admin should have the master key and the algorithm used to generate the key pairs

Comment: I know how asymmetric crypto works. My question is whether it's possible to derive public/private keys from a "masterkey". And if so, how?

Comment: yes, it is possible - you just generate the key pairs according to BIP39 for example. Check https://medium.com/coinmonks/hierarchical-deterministic-wallets-ethereum-589f8a359b81 or https://medium.com/@harshagoli/so-you-want-to-build-an-ethereum-hd-wallet-cb2b7d7e4998

Comment: i derived a public key from a master key and it seems like i cannot decrypt text with my masterPrivateKey. Do you know why?  https://gist.github.com/mx0c/3e8c0996a1655786f54b37af1ba1bd3c

Comment: You should use privateKey not masterPrivateKey, but as you know how to get privateKey from the master, it should be enough for the admin

Comment: Unfortunately this is not feasible for my use case. Thank you anyways.